# JAVA disable button while the user has not selected a file

Tags: java, swing, isenabled

I want to disable my mergeButton when the user has not selected both PDF'S.
How would I go about doing this? I tried to do a while loop to check if `file1` and `file2` are null but the loop does not terminate.

```
package pdfMerge;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility;

import java.awt.event.*;


public class pdfMerger extends JFrame {
    private static final String ActionEvent = null;
    private JButton choose1, choose2, mergeButton;
    private JFileChooser fileChooser1, fileChooser2;
    private JPanel contentsPane;
    private int returnValue1, returnValue2;
    private File file1, file2;
    private String fileName1, fileName2;
    private boolean valid;


    public pdfMerger(){
        super("PDF Merger");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addComponents();
        addAction();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void addComponents(){

        contentsPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        add(contentsPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        choose1 = new JButton("Choose 1st pdf");
        choose2 = new JButton("Choose 2nd pdf");

        mergeButton = new JButton("Merge");



        fileChooser1 = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser2 = new JFileChooser();

        contentsPane.add(choose1);
        contentsPane.add(choose2);
        contentsPane.add(mergeButton);

    }

    public void addAction(){
        choose1.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

                                if (event.getSource() == choose1){
                                    returnValue1 = fileChooser1.showOpenDialog(null);
                                    if (returnValue1 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                                        file1 = fileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
                                        fileName1 = file1.toString();
                                        fileName1 = fileName1.replace("\\", "\\\\");
                                        System.out.println(fileName1);


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
        );
        choose2.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                                if (event.getSource() == choose2){
                                    returnValue2 = fileChooser2.showOpenDialog(null);
                                    if (returnValue2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                                        file2 = fileChooser2.getSelectedFile();
                                        fileName2 = file2.toString();
                                        fileName2 = fileName2.replace("\\", "\\\\");
                                        System.out.println(fileName2);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
        );

        mergeButton.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){


                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){


                        PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
                        ut.addSource(fileName1);
                        ut.addSource(fileName2);
                        ut.setDestinationFileName("C:\\Users\\Shaheedul\\Desktop\\MergedPDF.pdf");
                        try {
                            ut.mergeDocuments();
                        } catch (Exception error){
                            System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
                        }
                    }
                }
        );


    }
    }
```

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, but here's what I'd try: Disable the mergeButton at the start of the program, and only enable it from choose1 and choose2's action listeners if both file1 and file2 are set.

Comment: Your current UI is not very user friendly. You should be displaying the selected file after you click each "choose" button so the user has a visual confirmation of what file has been selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: Set the mergeButton or its Action disabled to begin with:

```
mergeButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Then in the action listeners of your file choosing buttons, set the mergeButton enabled if 2 files have been chosen.

e.g. note major comments marked by `// !!`,

```
// !! class names should begin with upper case letter
public class PdfMerger extends JFrame {
    // ...
    private JButton choose1, choose2, mergeButton;
    // ...

    public PdfMerger() {
        super("PDF Merger");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(500, 500); // advise against this
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addComponents();
        addAction();
        setVisible(true);

        // !!
        mergeButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    // ...

    public void addAction() {
        choose1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                if (event.getSource() == choose1) {
                    returnValue1 = fileChooser1.showOpenDialog(null);
                    if (returnValue1 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        file1 = fileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
                        fileName1 = file1.toString();
                        fileName1 = fileName1.replace("\\", "\\\\");
                        System.out.println(fileName1);

                        // !! added
                        mergeButton.setEnabled(bothFilesChosen());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        choose2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (event.getSource() == choose2) {
                    returnValue2 = fileChooser2.showOpenDialog(null);
                    if (returnValue2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        file2 = fileChooser2.getSelectedFile();
                        fileName2 = file2.toString();
                        fileName2 = fileName2.replace("\\", "\\\\");
                        System.out.println(fileName2);

                        // !! added
                        mergeButton.setEnabled(bothFilesChosen());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // ....

    }

    // !!
    private boolean bothFilesChosen() {
        return (file1 != null && file1.exists() && file2 != null && file2.exists());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, when you have a choose button you should probably display the selected file in a Swing components so the user has a visual clue as to what file has been selected. If you don't display the value how does the user know they have clicked both buttons? Also, if the "Merge" button is disable, how does the user know which "select" button to click to enable the merge button?

So, in this case you could use a non-editable text field. Then you can add a `DocumentListener` to each text field. Whenever the text is changed in either field you then check to see the "Merge" button should be enabled/disabled.

Here is an example of this approach:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DataEntered implements DocumentListener
{
    private JButton button;
    private List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    public DataEntered(JButton button)
    {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void addTextField(JTextField textField)
    {
        textFields.add( textField );
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( this );
    }

    public boolean isDataEntered()
    {
        for (JTextField textField : textFields)
        {
            if (textField.getText().trim().length() == 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    private void checkData()
    {
        button.setEnabled( isDataEntered() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JButton submit = new JButton( "Submit" );
        submit.setEnabled( false );

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

        DataEntered de = new DataEntered( submit );
        de.addTextField( textField1 );
        de.addTextField( textField2 );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(submit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```